# Seat booking system information for C# Application

Tags: c#-2.0

can any one give me the suggetion to how to start and which control is the best to show the seats for booking reservation.i am using Visual Studio 2005 C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://code.daypilot.org/34704/restaurant-table-reservation-tutorial-asp-net-c-vb-net) sample. I hope it has something similar to what you are looking to develop.

Comment: Thanks for Replay, in the sample they used **DayPilotSchedular** controler. i am using vs 2.0 C#.